# Why sscanf doesn't fill the variable?

Tags: c, gcc, printf, scanf

I wonder why the value of `i` is `0` after `sscanf` has been previously called. I was expecting value of `i` to be modified.

I am using cygwin gcc in windows 7, version 3.4.4

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int i = 0;

    printf("\nread value %d\n", sscanf(&a, "%d", &i));
    printf("\nvalue is %d\n", i);
    printf("\nbuffer is %s\n", a);
}
```

output is

> read value is 0
>
> value is 0
>
> buffer is some special characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the first argument to sscanf should be a pointer to char, but you're passing in a pointer to a char array, which is the wrong type. That's only tangential to the question though.

To answer your question: sscanf (like the other *scanf functions, too) only writes a value if the format specifier for that value is matched in the string. So if you have the format specifier "%d", an int will be written to the given int pointer only if the string starts with a number. As you said yourself, your string only contains garbage: the (unprintable) characters with values 1 through 5 followed by whatever's in memory after `a`. So it doesn't start with a number and thus no number is written.

Comment: ya i got it. I thought like `sscanf` will read first 4 byes (1, 2, 3, 4) and it will try to print some big number with that combination of 4 bytes value. Actually it will read only if each byte of `a` contains value from 48 to 57( 0 to 9). Thanks for ur explanation.

Comment: I have another doubt about sscanf. consider `unsigned char a[3] = 0;` buffer. And consider i am stroing some valid numbers in first 2 byte. So `printf("%s", a)` is printing some value (`75`). In this case if I do `sscanf(&a, "%d", &i)` Will this statement tries to read 4th byte or it will simply quit at 3 byte itself, once `\0` is met.

Comment: @rajaashok It will read up to the first non-digit character, which in this case would be '\0'. Oh and also: as I indicated earlier, the first argument to `sscanf` should be `a`, not `&a`.

Answer (score 1):

sscanf is for STRINGS, not an array of chars without terminating character \0.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/

> Read formatted data from string Reads data from str and stores them
>   according to the parameter format into the locations given by the
>   additional arguments. Locations pointed by each additional argument
>   are filled with their corresponding type of value specified in the
>   format string.

Answer (score 1):

There's no unexpected behavior in your code. Note that function [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/) reads data from given string and *"returns the number of variables filled"*. You are passing a `char` array `a` as a source to retrieve data from it and not only that it does not contain any digits (`1` is not the same as `'1'`) it is also not null-terminated (`'\0'` is missing).

By `"%d"` you specify that decimal integer should be read, but there are no decimal integers in the given array thus `sscanf` doesn't read any numbers and `i` stays untouched. Function returns `0` indicating that no variable was filled.

Change the declaration of the array you are passing to the `sscanf` to valid string and it will yield the desired behavior. Try `char a[] = "1 2 3"`.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you what you expected.

`a` is *already a pointer*, so simply `a` is sufficient as first parameter for `sscanf`. It's probably a good idea to put 0 (i.e, `\0`) as last entry in `a` since you are passing it off to both `sscanf` and `printf` which expect to print a *null*-terminated string.

I also changed the type of `i` to `unsigned char` to match the data your are reading from.

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0};
    unsigned char i = 0;

    printf("\nread value %d\n", sscanf(a, "%c", &i));
    printf("\nvalue of i is %d\n", i);
    printf("\nbuffer is %s\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Note: You were previously getting 0 because `sscanf` failed to "read" any data for you from `a`.